# How to use autotools to build Python interface at same time as library

Tags: c++, python, swig, autotools, autoconf

I currently have a library written in C++, building with the GNU autotools, and I'd like to add a Python interface to it.  Using SWIG I have developed the interface, but I'm having some trouble figuring out how integrate compilation of the Python module in with the rest of the process.

I have looked into AM_PATH_PYTHON but this macro doesn't seem to set the include path for Python.h, so when I compile my module I get a bunch of errors about missing include files.  Is there a way to get the Python include path and ldflags out of AM_PATH_PYTHON?

Just for the record I don't think it will be possible to use Python's distutils method (setup.py) as this requires the location of the library in order to link the new module.  Since the library has not yet been installed at compile time, I would have to use a relative path (e.g. ../src/lib.so) which of course would break once the Python module was installed (as the library is then in /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib instead.)

EDIT:

Now it can find the .h file it's compiling, but after installing it (in the correct location) Python can't load the module.  The code produces foo.so, and when I "import foo" I get this:

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initfoo)
```

If however I rename it from foo.so to _foo.so then it loads and runs fine, except I have to "import _foo" which I'd rather not have to do.  When I follow the SWIG instructions to produce _foo.so in the current directory "import foo" works, so I am not sure why it breaks when the library is installed in the site directory.

EDIT2:

Turns out the problem was I forgot to copy foo.py produced by SWIG into the install directory alongside _foo.so.  Once I did this everything worked as expected!  Now I just have to figure out some automake rules to copy a file into the install dir...

Comment: To copy a non-executable file into the dir, you'll probably want something like `pkgpythondir_DATA = foo.py`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find the include path, I'd use `python-config`. The trick is to use the `python-config` corresponding to the python installed in `$PYTHON`.

```
AM_PATH_PYTHON
AC_ARG_VAR([PYTHON_INCLUDE], [Include flags for python, bypassing python-config])
AC_ARG_VAR([PYTHON_CONFIG], [Path to python-config])
AS_IF([test -z "$PYTHON_INCLUDE"], [
  AS_IF([test -z "$PYTHON_CONFIG"], [
    AC_PATH_PROGS([PYTHON_CONFIG],
                  [python$PYTHON_VERSION-config python-config],
                  [no],
                  [`dirname $PYTHON`])
    AS_IF([test "$PYTHON_CONFIG" = no], [AC_MSG_ERROR([cannot find python-config for $PYTHON.])])
  ])
  AC_MSG_CHECKING([python include flags])
  PYTHON_INCLUDE=`$PYTHON_CONFIG --includes`
  AC_MSG_RESULT([$PYTHON_INCLUDE])
])
```

Another alternative is to poke around in the `distutils.sysconfig` module (this has nothing to do with using distutils to build your code). Run `python -c "import distutils.sysconfig; help(distutils.sysconfig)"` and have a look.

Comment: Thanks - this worked, however now I am having troubles with the final .so binary, I've updated the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the autoconf macro I call from my ``configure.ac` to find the Python include directory (PYTHONINC) and the Python installation directory (via AM_PATH_PYTHON).

```
AC_DEFUN([adl_CHECK_PYTHON], 
 [AM_PATH_PYTHON([2.0])
  AC_CACHE_CHECK([for $am_display_PYTHON includes directory],
    [adl_cv_python_inc],
    [adl_cv_python_inc=`$PYTHON -c "from distutils import sysconfig; print sysconfig.get_python_inc()" 2>/dev/null`])
  AC_SUBST([PYTHONINC], [$adl_cv_python_inc])])
```

Then my `wrap/python/Makefile.am` builds two Swig modules using Libtool like this :

```
SUBDIRS = . cgi-bin ajax tests

AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(PYTHONINC) -I$(top_srcdir)/src $(BUDDY_CPPFLAGS) \
              -DSWIG_TYPE_TABLE=spot

EXTRA_DIST = spot.i buddy.i
python_PYTHON = $(srcdir)/spot.py $(srcdir)/buddy.py
pyexec_LTLIBRARIES = _spot.la _buddy.la

MAINTAINERCLEANFILES = \
  $(srcdir)/spot_wrap.cxx $(srcdir)/spot.py \
  $(srcdir)/buddy_wrap.cxx $(srcdir)/buddy.py

## spot

_spot_la_SOURCES = $(srcdir)/spot_wrap.cxx $(srcdir)/spot_wrap.h
_spot_la_LDFLAGS = -avoid-version -module
_spot_la_LIBADD = $(top_builddir)/src/libspot.la

$(srcdir)/spot_wrap.cxx: $(srcdir)/spot.i
        $(SWIG) -c++ -python -I$(srcdir) -I$(top_srcdir)/src $(srcdir)/spot.i


$(srcdir)/spot.py: $(srcdir)/spot.i
        $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) spot_wrap.cxx

## buddy

_buddy_la_SOURCES = $(srcdir)/buddy_wrap.cxx
_buddy_la_LDFLAGS = -avoid-version -module $(BUDDY_LDFLAGS)

$(srcdir)/buddy_wrap.cxx: $(srcdir)/buddy.i
        $(SWIG) -c++ -python $(BUDDY_CPPFLAGS) $(srcdir)/buddy.i

$(srcdir)/buddy.py: $(srcdir)/buddy.i
        $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) buddy_wrap.cxx
```

The above rules are such that the result of Swig is considered as a source file (i.e. distributed in the tarball) in the same way as a Bison-generated parser would be.  This way the final user do not need Swig installed.

When you run `make`, the `*.so` files are hidden by Libtool in some `.libs/` directory, but after `make install` they get copied to the right place.

The only trick is how to use the modules from inside the source directory before running `make install`.  E.g. while running `make check`.   For that case, I generate (with `configure`) a script called `run` that sets `PYTHONPATH` prior to running any `python` script, and I execute all my tests cases through this `run` script.  Here is the contents of `run.in`, before `configure` substitutes any value:

```
# Darwin needs some help in figuring out where non-installed libtool
# libraries are (on this platform libtool encodes the expected final
# path of dependent libraries in each library).
modpath='../.libs:@top_builddir@/src/.libs:@top_builddir@/buddy/src/.libs'

# .. is for the *.py files, and ../.libs for the *.so.  We used to
# rely on a module called ltihooks.py to teach the import function how
# to load a Libtool library, but it started to cause issues with
# Python 2.6.
pypath='..:../.libs:@srcdir@/..:@srcdir@/../.libs:$PYTHONPATH'

test -z "$1" &&
  PYTHONPATH=$pypath DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$modpath exec @PYTHON@

case $1 in
  *.py)
    PYTHONPATH=$pypath DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$modpath exec @PYTHON@ "$@";;
  *.test)
    exec sh -x "$@";;
  *)
    echo "Unknown extension" >&2
    exit 2;;
esac
```

If you want to see all this in action in a real project, you can get it from https://spot.lrde.epita.fr/install.html

Answer (score 1):

## Building Manually on the Command Line

Without adding the SWIG steps to your makefiles, you can build a SWIG extension using these commands (if you have source_file.cpp and your_extension.i to create your python module) :

```
  # creation of your_extension_wrap.cpp
  swig -c++ -python -o your_extension_wrap.cpp your_extension.i
  # creation of your_extension_wrap.o, source_file.o and your_extension.py
  g++ -fPIC -c your_extension_wrap.cpp source_file.cpp -I/usr/include/python2.7
  # creation of the library _your_extension.so
  g++ -shared your_extension_wrap.o source_file.o -o _your_extension.so
```

**Note**: It’s important to prefix the name of the shared object with an underscore, otherwise Python won’t be able to find it when import your_extension is executed.

## Adding SWIG to Autoconf

I writted a little program in Python in which I need a single file written in C++ (eg. rounding method).

You need additional Autoconf macros to enable SWIG support. As noted by johanvdw, it will be more easy if you use these two m4 macro : ax_pck_swig and ax_swig_python. I downloaded it [from the Autoconf Macro Archive](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/The-Macros.html#The-Macros) and placed it in the m4 subdirectory of my project tree:

```
trunk
    ├── configure.ac
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── m4
    │   ├── ax_pkg_swig.m4
    │   ├── ax_swig_python.m4
    │   ├── libtool.m4
    │   ├── lt~obsolete.m4
    │   ├── ltoptions.m4
    │   ├── ltsugar.m4
    │   └── ltversion.m4
    ├── Makefile.am
    ├── rounding_swig
    │   ├── compile.txt
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── Makefile.am
    │   ├── rnd_C.cpp
    │   ├── rounding.i
    │   ├── rounding_wrap.cpp
    └── src
        ├── cadna_add.py
        ├── cadna_computedzero.py
        ├── cadna_convert.py
        ├── __init__.py
        └── Makefile.am
```

When you place the two m4 macro in a subdirectory, you need to add this line to your trunk/Makefile.am:

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
```

Now, let see trunk/configure.ac :

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69]) # Check autoconf version 
AC_INIT(CADNA_PY, 1.0.0, cadna-team@lip6.fr) # Name of your software
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([rounding_swig/rnd_C.cpp]) # Name of the c++ source
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR(m4)     # Indicate where are your m4 macro
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS(config.h)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE

AC_DISABLE_STATIC #enable shared libraries

# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_LIBTOOL  # check libtool
AC_PROG_CXX  # check c++ compiler
AM_PATH_PYTHON(2.3) # check python version
AX_PKG_SWIG(1.3.21) # check swig version
AX_SWIG_ENABLE_CXX # fill some variable usefull later
AX_SWIG_PYTHON # same

# Checks for header files.
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([fenv.h stdlib.h string.h]) # any header needed by your c++ source
# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.
AC_CHECK_HEADER_STDBOOL
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T
# Checks for library functions.
AC_FUNC_MALLOC
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([fesetround memset strstr])

AC_CONFIG_FILES([
        Makefile
    src/Makefile
    rounding_swig/Makefile
        ])

LIBPYTHON="python$PYTHON_VERSION" # define the python interpreter
LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -l$LIBPYTHON"
AC_OUTPUT
```

## Adding SWIG to Automake

In your trunk/Makefile.am, you need to do the following:

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4

# Indicate the subdir of c++ file and python file
SUBDIRS = src rounding_swig

# Indicate a list of all the files that are part of the package, but
# are not installed by default and were not specified in any other way
EXTRA_DIST= \
rounding_swig/rounding.i \
rounding_swig/testrounding.py \
rounding_swig/testrounding.cpp
```

In your trunk/src/Makefile.am :

```
# Python source files that will be install in prefix/lib/name_of_your_python_interpreter/site-packages/name_of_your_project
pkgpython_PYTHON = cadna_add.py cadna_computedzero.py cadna_convert.py
```

The difficult part is in trunk/rounding_swig/Makefile.am. It creates a library .la and a _your_extension.so and place it in *prefix*/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/name_of_the_project/.

```
# Name of the cpp source file
BUILT_SOURCES = rounding_wrap.cpp
# Name of the swig source file
SWIG_SOURCES = rounding.i
# Python source files that will be install in prefix/lib/name_of_your_python_interpreter/site-packages/name_of_your_project
pkgpython_PYTHON = rounding.py __init__.py
pkgpyexec_LTLIBRARIES = _rounding.la
_rounding_la_SOURCES = rounding_wrap.cpp $(SWIG_SOURCES) rnd_C.cpp
_rounding_la_CPPFLAGS = $(AX_SWIG_PYTHON_CPPFLAGS) -I$(top_srcdir)/rounding_swig -I/usr/include/python@PYTHON_VERSION@ -lpython@PYTHON_VERSION@
_rounding_la_LDFLAGS = -module

rounding_wrap.cpp: $(SWIG_SOURCES)
    $(SWIG) $(AX_SWIG_PYTHON_OPT) -I$(top_srcdir)/rounding_swig -I/usr/include/python@PYTHON_VERSION@ -o $@ $<
```

Af the end, if you don't have the 5 others macro, you can obtain it by typing :

```
autoreconf -i
```

Finally, to install your project :

```
libtoolize && aclocal && autoheader && autoconf && automake -a -c
./configure --prefix=<install prefix>
make
make install
```

PS : [Here](http://realmike.org/blog/2010/07/18/building-swig-python-extensions-on-gnulinux/#automake) is an outdated but simple tutorial that helped me (outdated because it used ac_pkg_swig.m4 which fails with new version of swig).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but since I landed here anyway: there are some m4 macros which make compilation of python bindings using swig very easy:

http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_pkg_swig.html
and
http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_swig_python.html